# addEventListener always creates a new audio element, due to which i am unable to pause my once played audio

Tags: javascript, audio, addeventlistener

I have created a click event listener then added a function in it which conatin some parameters, according to that parameters i am creating an audio element, which i play in further steps. Problem arises when i wish to pause that same audio after detecting another click, it never happens because it creates a new audio element on every click with same values and pause it, although that new audio element was never played and the first audio element created keeps playing.

```
let check = true;
masterPlayButton.addEventListener("click", function (i) {
  minorPlayPause(i);
});
```

```
function minorPlayPause(x) {
  let audio = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
 if (check == true) {
    check = false;
    audio.play();
    };
  } else {
    check = true;
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

I tried creating audio element outside the event listener so that everytime a new audio element is not created but it doesnt work because i want to create audio element according to the parameters provided from  click data.
Also, i tried to put another event listener inside the 'if' (as written in the provided code) to detect the pause on the same audio element, but it didnt worked.
I just want to pause the same audio on second click.

A helping hand is most appreciable !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Problem arises when I wish to pause that same audio after detecting another click, it never happens because it creates a new audio element on every click".

A new `audio` object is created on every click because your code says to create a new `audio` object on every click:

```
function minorPlayPause(x) {
  let audio = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
  // more code
}
```

If you only want to create a new `audio` object when one is not currently playing then you need to move the `let audio = new ...` line into the conditional:

```
function minorPlayPause(x) {
  if (check == true) {
    let audio = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
    check = false;
    audio.play();
  } else {
    check = true;
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

You will also need to store the old `audio` object somewhere so that you can access it later in order to pause it.

```
function minorPlayPause(x) {
  if (check == true) {
    let audio = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
    check = false;
    audio.play();
    oldAudio = audio // could make this a global variable, or return it from this function
  } else {
    check = true;
    oldAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the extra `check` variable -- you can use the built-in `audio.paused` property. If the audio is not paused, then it's playing. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
let check = true;
let audio = new Audio();
masterPlayButton.addEventListener("click", function (i) {
  minorPlayPause(i);
});

function minorPlayPause(x) {
 if (check == true) {
    check = false;
    audio.src = "songs/" + x + ".mp3"
    audio.play();
    };
  } else {
    check = true;
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this only works in case where only one audio plays at the time (which I understand is the normal use).

More infor here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio